# Building a project with CMake, Ninja and Clang++ without MSVC

Tags: windows, cmake, clang++, ninja

I'm currently working on a C++ project that build successfully on Linux using CMake, Make & GCC, and also on Windows using CMake & VS2015.

For some reason, i'd like to build it using the same toolchain everywhere, so i planned to use CMake, Clang & Ninja.
I started to try to build it on Windows, but i did not find any documentation to build using libc++ and without anything from the MSVC toolchain.

Am I forced to install MSVC build tools in order to build with CMake & Clang ?

Comment: If you want to use Ninja as a *build* tool, just pass `-G Ninja` option to CMake when configure the project.

Answer (score 0):

Use a MinGW-w64 of GCC on Windows (e.g. the one from http://winlibs.com, or any other one listed at http://mingw-w64.org/).

If you combine this with the MSYS2 shell (http://www.msys2.org/), you can build a lot using the same tools as on Linux (autoconf, CMake, meson, ...).